# Extjs 6- get grid Panel cell value

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, cell

I want to get all grid cell value, so I test the first cell with bellow code:

```
var array = [];
var grid = Ext.getCmp('grid');
var selection = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
console.log(array.push(selection)); //it returns 1
```

however

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('grid');
var selection = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
console.log(selection);//returns undefined
```

any suggestions? thanks

Comment: thank you, yes, I've tried it but what if I want get all value, I mean without `listeners`

Comment: You want to cell value of selected rows right ?

Comment: I need to get cell value without any event, as above code.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this first you need to access all the columns of row and then respective cell of the columns. And after you can get all the values of respective cell.

You can get this by following code.

```
select: function(selModel, record, index, options){
                var ColLength = this.columns.length;
                for(var i=0; i<ColLength; i++){
                     var colName = this.getHeaderContainer().getHeaderAtIndex(i+1).dataIndex;
                    cellvalue = record.data[colName];
                    alert(cellvalue);
                }

            }
```

I made a fiddler for you where you check your complete flow. [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1hu0)